Sprintboot Opentelemetry with spring-boot-starter Error
I am trying to enable opentelemetry leveraging sprint-boot-starter. I added io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter to the build.gradle file. However, the application throws the following error on startup:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk]: Factory method 'autoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk' threw exception with message: io/opentelemetry/sdk/autoconfigure/spi/internal/AutoConfigureListener Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.spi.internal.AutoConfigureListener

portion of the build.gradle file:
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-bom:1.40.0-alpha'             
implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-instrumentation-bom-alpha:2.6.0'             
implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter:2.6.0'             
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure:1.40.0'             
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi:1.40.0'

Not sure what is missing with the dependency. Any idea on how to address this? I found a similar issue mentioned here 11812
Thanks

people would probably be able to help you further if you would have provided your build.gradle file

add it to the original question - the comment is not readable

done. Thanks for your help!

in your case it is just a dependencies versions mismatch (you have incompatible version there) - just follow this documentation page on how to add the dependencies

Thanks cleaned it up and now the error is gone. However, i only see the traces for actuator health endpoint and not for any application specific services. I would think the application is enabled by default. do we need to specify any settings?

Actually, for this there are no traces and i get a 404 exporting the traces. I don't see the URL being connected to. I did specify URL with otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=. Any idea where to see/provide the collector URL for starter. Thanks

I see this error in the log: This is pointing to a java args commandline value. not sure what it is trying to read -> io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.ManifestResourceProvider readManifest
WARNING: Error reading manifest
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: --add-exports=...

The micrometer based approach is working so will pursue it instead. thanks for your help on this!
